# Trying to create a method and a property with same name

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Trying to have a method and a property with the same name:

As a property used to access the value: `if (myObject.propMethod() == queryVal)`
A method, used to assign to propMethod: `myObject.propMethod(newVal)`

I have defined the following:

```
        // the property: 
        myObject.propMethod = ko.observable();   // disregard the knockout 'ko' for this question  
        // the method: 
        myObject.prototype.propMethod = function (value) {
            myObject.propMethod = value;
            return target; // supports chaining
        };
```

Lacking experience and exposure to javascript: it seems to be working, but I'd like to verify if there's something I am not accounting for.

EDIT: Per comments below it appears that my assignment actually calls knockout's function, so my "prototype" is never executed. How do i get a structure that allows me to execute additional logic on assignment?

Comment: You say to disregard the knockout bit, but setting a `property` as a knockout observable is making it a function, and to set the value you call the function passing in the value so your code won't work as you intend.

Comment: `prototype` creates a property that will also be present in other *new* Objects.

Comment: @RichardDalton, so in my assignment call `myObject.propMethod(newVal)`, I am actually calling the ko function to do the assignment. I guess it returns, when done, the original observable (just like my "prototype" attempt) so chaining is possible and everything appears to work. I have edited the question to ask how to accomplish an assignment that also executes my custom logic (not just ko's observable thing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a property and method seperately to assign a value to property.

just assign to it directly.

```
        // the property: 
    myObject.propMethod = ko.observable(); 
    // the method: 
    myObject.propMethod = value;
```

In this case, Knockout has to make it observable (for two way binding. update whenever you change the values.) As knockout makes it as a method to observe, you have to read knockout observable property by putting () after the property name.

Comment: I am looking for a true property/method behavior - I need to execute additional logic.

Comment: What do you mean by true property/method behavior? It would nice if you could create a demo in JSFiddle

Comment: I mean additional code that executes on each "get" or "set"; getters and setters let you execute additional code, other than getting and setting the value.

Answer (score 0):

A Knockout `observable` *is* a method of the ViewModel it belongs to; it's a getter/setter, so you can use it *exactly* the way you describe in your second paragraph. You don't need to do anything special to enable this behavior; it's built-in.

If you're trying to achieve this effect independent of Knockout, just create a getter/setter factory function:

```
function getterSetter(initVal) {
  var myValue=initVal; //Closures are cool!
  return function(val) {
    if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
      myValue = val;
    }
    return myValue;
  }
}
```

and then

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.propMethod = getterSetter();
myObject.anotherPropMethod = getterSetter('hello');
...
myObject.propMethod('world');
alert(myObject.anotherPropMethod()+' '+myObject.propMethod();
myObject.anotherPropMethod('goodbye');
alert(myObject.anotherPropMethod()+' '+myObject.propMethod();
```